# how to split rows of a dataframe in multiple rows based on start date and end date?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a dataset with a starting date and an enddate, and I want to split the rows in this dataframe based on the year in the period. Take this data frame for example:

```
df <- data.frame("starting_date"=as.Date("2015-06-01"),"end_date"=as.Date("2017-09-30"))
```

It should be split into 3 rows, one with starting date 2015-06-01 and end date 2015-12-31, one with starting date 2016-01-01 and end date 2016-12-31, and one with starting date 2017-01-01 and end date 2017-09-30. Any idea how to do this? It should look like this in the end:

```
  starting_date   end_date
1    2015-06-01 2015-12-31
2    2016-01-01 2016-12-31
3    2017-01-01 2017-09-30
```

EDIT: I have adjusted the code to work in base R.

EDIT2: I tried

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df[1,]
df2 <- df[-1,]
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  for (j in year(df$starting_date[i]):year(df$end_date[i])) 
  {
    df2 <- bind_rows(df2,df[i,])  
  }
}
```

It works, but it is impossibly slow.

EDIT3:
I managed to replicate the lines equal to the number of years involved:

```
df2 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)),year(df$end_date)-year(df$starting_date)+1),]
```

Now I would need another column with the years like this:

```
  starting_date   end_date  years
1    2015-06-01 2017-09-30   2015
2    2015-06-01 2017-09-30   2016
3    2015-06-01 2017-09-30   2017
```

Once I am here it is easy to get the required end result.... Any idea on how to do this? 
I tried to make a seperate vector with the years, in order to cbind it with df2, but it didn't work....

```
years <- lapply(df,function(x) seq(x[,"starting_date"],length.out=x[,"year"]))
```

EDIT4:
Finally managed to do it with the help of this post: [R Create a time sequence as xts index based on two columns in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511092/r-create-a-time-sequence-as-xts-index-based-on-two-columns-in-data-frame)
The code can probably be improved upon a lot, but it works....

```
diffs <- abs(with(df, year(starting_date)-year(end_date)))+1
df.rep <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), times=diffs), ]
reps <- rep(diffs, times=diffs)

dates.l <- apply(
  df[colnames(df) %in% c("starting_date", "end_date")], 1, 
  function(x) {
    seq(min(year(as.Date(x))), max(year(as.Date(x))))
  })

years <- do.call(c, dates.l)
df.long <- cbind(df.rep, reps, years)
df.long$yearstart <- as.Date(paste0(year(df.long$years),"-01-01"))
df.long$yearend <- as.Date(paste0(year(df.long$years),"-12-31"))
df.long$starting_date2 <- pmax(df.long$starting_date,df.long$yearstart)
df.long$end_date2 <- pmin(df.long$end_date,df.long$yearend)
```

Comment: Write a complete code example that works in a new R session. `date` is not a base R function... eg, `x = as.Date(c("2015-06-01", "2017-09-30"))` seems to fit.

Comment: @Frank technically... `date` is a base R function, but it does not take any arguments.

Comment: @lmo Ah, interesting. I think I've never seen that

Comment: Yeah. I found  when looking into the `timestamp` function at some point recently.

Comment: I've edited the code, so it works in base R now.

Comment: @Cuchulainn your data.frame has 1 row and two variables. It is not clear what you want. Maybe start with `myDays <- seq(df$a, df$b, by="day")` to get all days in between. Then maybe `myList <- split(myDays, format(myDays, "%Y"))`. Finally use `sapply(myDays, head, 1)` and `sapply(myDays, tail, 1)`.

Comment: @lmo I've added the desired result to give you an idea. Every row can have a different start and end date. If they are in the same year no split is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#sample data
df <- data.frame("starting_date" = as.Date(c("2015-06-01", "2013-06-01", "2016-02-11")),
                 "end_date" = as.Date(c("2017-09-30", "2017-11-11", "2017-01-01")),
                 col3=c('AAA','BBB', 'CCC'),
                 col4=c('33445454','565664', '123'))

df1 <- df[,1:2] %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  do(rbind(data.frame(matrix(as.character(c(
    .$starting_date, 
    seq(.$starting_date, .$end_date, by=1)[grep("\\d{4}-12-31|\\d{4}-01-01", seq(.$starting_date, .$end_date, by=1))], 
    .$end_date)), ncol=2, byrow=T)))) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("starting_date", "end_date")) %>%
  mutate(starting_date= as.Date(starting_date, format= "%Y-%m-%d"),
         end_date= as.Date(end_date, format= "%Y-%m-%d"))

#add temporary columns to the original and expanded date column dataframes
df$row_idx <- seq(1:nrow(df))
df$temp_col <- (year(df$end_date) - year(df$starting_date)) +1
df1 <- cbind(df1,row_idx = rep(df$row_idx,df$temp_col))

#join both dataframes to get the final result
final_df <- left_join(df1,df[,3:(ncol(df)-1)],by="row_idx") %>%
  select(-row_idx) 
final_df
```

Output is:

```
   starting_date   end_date col3     col4
1     2015-06-01 2015-12-31  AAA 33445454
2     2016-01-01 2016-12-31  AAA 33445454
3     2017-01-01 2017-09-30  AAA 33445454
4     2013-06-01 2013-12-31  BBB   565664
5     2014-01-01 2014-12-31  BBB   565664
6     2015-01-01 2015-12-31  BBB   565664
7     2016-01-01 2016-12-31  BBB   565664
8     2017-01-01 2017-11-11  BBB   565664
9     2016-02-11 2016-12-31  CCC      123
10    2017-01-01 2017-01-01  CCC      123
```

Comment: It works brilliantly for this example, but in reality I've got multiple other columns too. How do I adjust this code to include those other columns in the output?

Comment: @Cuchulainn pls refer my updated code. Hope it helps!

Comment: almost :-) It doesn't work when the end date is the first day of the year, like 2017-01-01.

Comment: Let's try now :)