# Expand start and end dates into a sequence of beginning and ending dates by calendar month

Tags: r

Given a table

```
id   start          end
1   22/03/2016    05/06/2016
2   17/08/2016    29/08/2016
3   22/09/2017    25/12/2017
```

I'm trying to split by Calendar month as the following table

```
id   start         end
1   22/03/2016    31/03/2016
1   01/04/2016    30/04/2016
1   01/05/2016    05/06/2016
2   17/08/2016    29/08/2016
3   22/09/2017    30/09/2017
3   01/10/2017    31/10/2017
3   01/11/2017    30/11/2017
3   01/12/2017    25/12/2017
```

I'm trying to modify a code extract from [how to split rows of a dataframe in multiple rows based on start date and end date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140352/how-to-split-rows-of-a-dataframe-in-multiple-rows-based-on-start-date-and-end-da?rq=1) , but I am not being able to modify correctly the code. The problem is generally in the months with 30 days, and maybe is easy but I am not still familiarized with regular expressions.

```
#sample data
df <- data.frame("starting_date" = as.Date(c("2016-03-22", "2016-08-17", "2017-09-12")),
             "end_date" = as.Date(c("2016-06-05", "2016-08-29", "2017-12-25")),
             col3=c('1','2', '3'))

df1 <- df[,1:2] %>% 
rowwise() %>%
do(rbind(data.frame(matrix(as.character(c(
.$starting_date, 

seq(.$starting_date, .$end_date, by=1)[grep("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-31|\\d{4}-\\d{2}-01", seq(.$starting_date, .$end_date, by=1))],

.$end_date)), ncol=2, byrow=T))
  )
) %>%
data.frame() %>%
`colnames<-`(c("starting_date", "end_date")) %>%
mutate(starting_date= as.Date(starting_date, format= "%Y-%m-%d"),
     end_date= as.Date(end_date, format= "%Y-%m-%d"))

#add temporary columns to the original and expanded date column dataframes
df$row_idx <- seq(1:nrow(df))
df$temp_col <- (year(df$end_date) - year(df$starting_date)) +1
df1 <- cbind(df1,row_idx = rep(df$row_idx,df$temp_col))

#join both dataframes to get the final result
final_df <- left_join(df1,df[,3:(ncol(df)-1)],by="row_idx") %>%
  select(-row_idx) 
final_df
```

If anyone knows how to modify the code or a better way to do it I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

We assume there is an error in the sample output in the question since the third row spans parts of two months and so should be split into two rows.

Define `Seq` which given one `start` and `end` Date variables produces a data.frame of `start` and `end` columns and then run it on each `id` using `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

Seq <- function(start, end) {
  ym <- seq(as.yearmon(start), as.yearmon(end), 1/12)
  starts <- pmax(start, as.Date(ym, frac = 0))
  ends <- pmin(end, as.Date(ym, frac = 1))
  unique(data.frame(start = starts, end = ends))
}

fmt <- "%d/%m/%Y"
DF %>%
  mutate(start = as.Date(start, fmt), end = as.Date(end, fmt)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(Seq(.$start, .$end)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     id start      end       
  <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2016-03-22 2016-03-31
2     1 2016-04-01 2016-04-30
3     1 2016-05-01 2016-05-31
4     1 2016-06-01 2016-06-05
5     2 2016-08-17 2016-08-29
6     3 2017-09-22 2017-09-30
7     3 2017-10-01 2017-10-31
8     3 2017-11-01 2017-11-30
9     3 2017-12-01 2017-12-25
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
id   start          end
1   22/03/2016    05/06/2016
2   17/08/2016    29/08/2016
3   22/09/2017    25/12/2017"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

So there's a probably a more elegant way to accomplish this and I feel like I've seen similar questions, but could not find a duplicate quickly, so here goes...

**SETUP**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c('1', '2', '3'),
  starting_date = as.Date(c("2016-03-22", "2016-08-17", "2017-09-12")),
  end_date = as.Date(c("2016-06-05", "2016-08-29", "2017-12-25")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df
#>   id starting_date   end_date
#> 1  1    2016-03-22 2016-06-05
#> 2  2    2016-08-17 2016-08-29
#> 3  3    2017-09-12 2017-12-25
```

**SOLUTION**

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    date_seq = list(seq.Date(starting_date, end_date, by = "month") %>% ceiling_date("month") - 1)
  ) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(
    new_end_date = if_else(row == max(row), end_date, date_seq),
    new_start_date = if_else(row == min(row), starting_date, floor_date(new_end_date, "month"))
  ) %>% 
  select(
    id, new_start_date, new_end_date
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>   id    new_start_date new_end_date
#>   <chr> <date>         <date>      
#> 1 1     2016-03-22     2016-03-31  
#> 2 1     2016-04-01     2016-04-30  
#> 3 1     2016-06-01     2016-06-05  
#> 4 2     2016-08-17     2016-08-29  
#> 5 3     2017-09-12     2017-09-30  
#> 6 3     2017-10-01     2017-10-31  
#> 7 3     2017-11-01     2017-11-30  
#> 8 3     2017-12-01     2017-12-25
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

Much of what's going on here takes place in the first `mutate` call which creates `date_seq`. To understand it, consider the following:

```
seq.Date(ymd("2016-03-22"), ymd("2016-06-05"), by = "month")
# [1] "2016-03-22" "2016-04-22" "2016-05-22"

seq.Date(ymd("2016-03-22"), ymd("2016-06-05"), by = "month") %>% 
  ceiling_date("month")
# [1] "2016-04-01" "2016-05-01" "2016-06-01"

seq.Date(ymd("2016-03-22"), ymd("2016-06-05"), by = "month") %>% 
  ceiling_date("month") - 1
# [1] "2016-03-31" "2016-04-30" "2016-05-31"
```

So basically, create a sequence of "end-of-month" dates between the original start and end dates. Putting this in a list-column allows us to organize by the id so that we `unnest` appropriately. Checkout the output after the end of the `unnest()`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    date_seq = list(seq.Date(starting_date, end_date, by = "month") %>% ceiling_date("month") - 1)
  ) %>%
  unnest()
```

From there I hope things are relatively straightforward. The `row_number` probably could have been replaced with something fancier like a `first/last`, but I thought this might be easier to follow.