# Split a date range in a single row to multiple rows with one row per month

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, data.table

I have a data frame with millions of rows in the below format

```
    id   value  start-date   end-date      duration_in_months
    100  120    2018-Jan-12  2019-Jan-12   12
```

I need to split this single row into multiple rows with one row for each month. Requesting help on the best approach to do the same with python pandas or in R data.table/dplyr

```
    id  value  start-date  end-date
    100  10   2018-Jan-12  2018-Jan-31
    100  10   2018-Feb-01  2018-Feb-28 
    100  10   2018-Mar-12  2018-Mar-31
    100  10   2018-Apr-12  2018-Apr-30
    .....
    100  10   2019-Jan-01  2018-Jan-12
```

have tried pd.date_range to create a start and end columns with

```
    pd.date_range("2018-Jan-12", "2019-Jan-12").strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist().
```

But this will require multiple steps to offset dates and month in starting and end rows and may not be the optimal approach

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844141/adding-rows-for-each-month-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-date

Comment: A similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844141/adding-rows-for-each-month-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-date

Comment: @gmds why did you remove the r-tag??

Comment: @Sotos This seems like a Python question to me...

Comment: @gmds It doesn't matter if it is in python code. OP might want an R implementation as well.

Comment: I have edited the question to ask for a solution using R as well, basis comments from @Sotos

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504279/expand-start-and-end-dates-into-a-sequence-of-beginning-and-ending-dates-by-cale